# JOIN SQL query over subsequent tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a doubt about how to properly use JOIN SQL queries.

Imagine that I have 3 tables. I want to make a RIGHT JOIN between two of them. This is, I want to show all the records from the left table and just those records from the right table where the join is equal. Once I have this, I want to make another JOIN (inner or whatever) between the table that was on the right (now is the LEFT table) and the third table (that is the RIGHT table). So that, I would have 3 tables connected. My problem is that I get a message error from access that is:

> The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous
>   outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a
>   separate query that performs the first join and then include that
>   query in your SQL statement.

So, Access is forcing me to use two separates queries but I don't want to use two. I think that this must be possible in just one. Am I right? Do you know if there is a method for this?

Thank you all.

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` indicates your either an SQL exptert or a beginner who doesn't know what you're doing! Stick to `LEFT JOIN` if an outer join is needed, so much easier to understand "main table left join optional data".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

Put the inner join first

Source : [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209755(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? Should have been a comment.